# Pass value to another viewcontroller according to tableviewcell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I added UIButton on each tableViewCell so that when I tap it, it can send a user to another viewController according to the text on the tableViewCell. I already used a singleTon with sharingManager to pass values between viewControllers and I set the title inside the function "setSelected" for each tableViewcell.

```
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
 SharingManager.sharedInstance.selectedCollege = self.CollegeLabel.text!

}
```

And then I fetch the value of "selectedCollege" and set the title on a different UIviewcontroller.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

 self.title = SharingManager.sharedInstance.selectedCollege
}
```

However, it does not set the title correctly as the title does not always match the text on the tableViewCell.

Comment: for each cell add a tag. now when you press a cell get its tag and you will know which button you pressed

Comment: It seems likely that `setSelected` is not being called on a button tap.  Can you add a print in that method to verify?

Comment: @PhillipMills I I did and it prints out the text on all the tableViewCells. Why do you think this happens?

Comment: @MarkLi let me know if I am wrong you need a way to pass data through one view controller to another when you touch a button on one cell of your first view controller?

Comment: It would be cleaner to remove the buttons and just connect the tableView itself to the segue to the detail controller. Then in prepareForSegue:sender get the tableView's indexPathForSelectedRow and pass the data forward from your dataSource at the associated indexPath

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use SharingManager? If you want to pass data between ViewControllers you can use the prepareForSegue method.

1. add a instance variable "titleOfSelectedRow" to your view controller
2. Create a segue from your source view controller to the destination view controller and set an identifier
3. In your button action call the performSegueWithIdentifier method and save the title of the selected row in your titleOfSelectedRow method
4. override the prepareForSegue method. In this method you can access the destinationViewController and set the title to the value of your titleOfSelectedRow variable.

Comment: I can't use segue between those two viewControllers for a complicated reason.

Comment: You should be able to use a segue for this. If it seems too complicated then you should reevaluate your approach

Answer (score 0):

Use `prepareForSegue` method. 
1) Set segue in storyboard
2) Make something like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let cntrl = segue.destinationViewController as? SecondViewController {
        cntrl.publicVar = 'your value'
    }
}
```

Also u can get indexOf selected tableView row. Example:

```
let selectedIndex : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
```

Another way - init viewController with storyboard ID and call pressent function

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to accomplish your need

Create a variable in the view controller you want to set title

```
class SecondVC: UIViewController {

//MARK: - Variables

var title : String = ""
.......
```

now on button click

```
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    let title = self.CollegeLabel.text!
    let secondVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondVC") as! GSMenuCategoryPriceVC

    secondVC.title = title
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)
}
```